# Call javascript to preserve filter state when traverse from other page via href

Tags: javascript, html

I have a number of webpages in a report each page has a checbox filter that if selected calls javascript to show hide some elements of the page, the checkbox filter enables to true, all pages are created in advance. The user can traverse from one pages by clocking on a url .

The trouble is because the pages are created in advance the filter always default to true, even if just set to false by user on previous page. I think I need to call some javascript to set the value of the filter to the value of the filter on the calling page but because traversing form page to page via a hyperlink I dont know how to call the Javascript.

FYI 
Html Filter

```
<div class="mb-2">
    <div class="form-group form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="showLabels" id="showLabels" checked="checked" onclick="toggleLabelsFilter(&#x27;showLabels&#x27;);">
        <label for="showLabels" id="showLabelslabel" class="form-check-label">
            Show Labels
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example html that will have elements hidden

```
<figure class="figure" style="position:relative">
            <a href="StatusReport00017_byfolder00021.html">
                <img src="../images/E__Melco_TestMusic_WAV_WAV_Antonin Dvorak; Itzhak Perlman, Daniel Barenboim, Samuel Sanders.jpg" class="figure-img" width="200" height="200">
            </a>
            <div style="position:absolute; top:144px;">
                <div class="badge ml-2 badge-primary">
                    12 files
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="position:absolute; top:166px;">
                <div class="badge ml-2 badge-success">
                    12&nbsp;MB
                </div>
                <div class="badge ml-2 badge-warning">
                    0&nbsp;Discogs
                </div>
            </div>
            <figcaption class="figure-caption">
                <a href="StatusReport00017_byfolder00021.html">
                    Antonin Dvorak; Itzhak Perlman, Daniel Barenboim, Samuel Sanders
                </a>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
```

Javascript

```
function toggleLabelsFilter(filterName)
{
      var checkbox = document.getElementById(filterName);
      if(checkbox.checked)
      {
             var badges = document.getElementsByClassName("badge");
             for (i = 0; i < badges.length; i++)
             {
               badges[i].style.visibility = "visible";
             }
      }
      else
      {
            var badges = document.getElementsByClassName("badge");
            for (i = 0; i < badges.length; i++)
            {
                badges[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
      }
}
```

**Edit Update**
Attempt based on comments

Called when user selects checkbox

```
function toggleLabelsFilter()
{
      var checkbox = document.getElementById("showLabels");
      if(checkbox.checked)
      {
             sessionStorage.setItem("showLabels", true);
             var badges = document.getElementsByClassName("badge");
             for (i = 0; i < badges.length; i++)
             {
               badges[i].style.visibility = "visible";
             }
      }
      else
      {
            sessionStorage.setItem("showLabels", false);
            var badges = document.getElementsByClassName("badge");
            for (i = 0; i < badges.length; i++)
            {
                badges[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
      }
}
```

Called when page loaded

```
function checkFilter()
{
    if(sessionStorage.getItem("showLabels")==true)
    {
        document.getElementById("showLabels").checked=true;
        var badges = document.getElementsByClassName("badge");
        for (i = 0; i < badges.length; i++)
        {
            badges[i].style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("showLabels").checked=false;
        var badges = document.getElementsByClassName("badge");
        for (i = 0; i < badges.length; i++)
        {
            badges[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you set a cookie of filters onClick and then read that cookie to decide what to display?

Comment: You can also store the state in localstorage.

Comment: I dont currenlty use cookies and would rather not even if I use local storage when would i make the call to actually check that local storage, want to keep as simple as possible

Comment: @Muhammad hi okay so i have create a javascript function that runs ononload() but not sure how to use local storage

Comment: @Muhammad i have followed your advice but cant quite get it working seems to set to the opposite of what it was previously set to

Comment: @PaulTaylor you can use `localStorage.setItem("activetab", "some-tab-index")` when clicking a tab and then call the `localStorage.getItem("activetab")` in your onload function and set the active tab. you should know traversing the DOM element to achieve this.

Comment: @Muhammad okay thanks seem to have ti working now

Comment: @Muhammad slight problem, works fine when serving the pages as a server, but can also just open the files as html files in a browser and then it just reverts to unchecked so I assume localStorage () doesnt work in this circumstances

Comment: @PaulTaylor thats right, with `file://` protocol it does not seems to work well.